# add the data in each row with different data contents php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a mysql table data. I want to start displaying the data taken from different databases and display as well as the added value of its data based on the value of the data in the first row. Essentially, I want the data values to increase in value in the second row and so on where the value of the data obtained from the sum of the first line, second and so on.

The following is an example of the data output:
[image: data output]

PHP code:

```
<?php
$channel=$_GET['channel'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM konten WHERE channel='$channel' ORDER BY id");
$no=1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($sql)) {;

    $sqlstart = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM start");
    $barisstart=mysql_fetch_row($sqlstart);
    $wak = strtotime($barisstart['1']);
    $waktuawal = date ("H.i", $wak);


    $dur = $row['7'];
    $durasi = gmdate("H.i", $dur);
    $startawal1 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' '.$waktuawal.':00');
    $startakhir1 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' '.$durasi.':00');
    $begin_day_unix1 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00');
    $jumlah_time1 = date('H.i', ($startawal1 + ($startakhir1 - $begin_day_unix1)));

    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td align="center"><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></td>';
        echo '<td align="center">'.$no++.'</td>';
        echo '<td align="center" width="10%" hidden>'.$row[0].'</td>';
        echo '<td align="center" width="30">'.$row[2].'</td>';
        echo '<td align="center" width="30">'.$waktuawal.'</td>';
        echo '<td align="center" width="80">'.$durasi.'</td>';
}
?>
```

I plan in the coding `$jumlah_time1` it will be displayed on the second line after `$waktuawal` is displayed in the first line.

Comment: additional examples, in the picture data value in column start is 00.16 and data value in column duration is 01.59, when second  row, i want to display in column start in second row is the sum of duration in first row, example 02.15

Answer (score 0):

Try an `inner join`!

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

I think this work for you, and try to use pdo or mysqli.

Comment: I am new in php mysql, can Did you give an example using pdo mysqli?